# Height of super view is not setting properly because of FlatList as its subview

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I am trying to create a FlatList within a View, but when I set the view's position as Absolute, it takes the total content size of the FlatList. But I want to keep the height of the View as the remaining screen size between Navigation Bar & Bottom bar, but I don't know how to achieve that.

Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react';

import { View, StyleSheet, SafeAreaView, FlatList, Image, } from 'react-native';
import { DARK_GREY_COLOR_CODE, GREY_COLOR_CODE, MAGENTA_COLOR_CODE } from '../Constant/Constants';


export default class ExplorePage extends React.Component {
  _renderTutorialList() {
  }

  render() {
    const sampleNameArray = [
      {
        id: 'bd7acbea-c1b1-46c2-aed5-3ad53abb28ba',
        title: 'Kinky',
      },
      {
        id: '3ac68afc-c605-48d3-a4f8-fbd91aa97f63',
        title: 'Waves/Loose Curls',
      },
      {
        id: '58694a0f-3da1-471f-bd96-145571e29d72',
        title: 'Curly',
        image_name: './Images/hairtype_thum_image.png',
      },
      {
        id: '58694a0f-3da1-471f-bd96-145571e29d79',
        title: 'Coily',
      },
    ];

    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={{flex:1, }}>
        <View style={{ flex: 1, position: 'absolute', width: '100%', backgroundColor: GREY_COLOR_CODE }}>
          <FlatList
            data={sampleNameArray}
            renderItem={({ item }) =>
              <View style={{width: '89.3%', height: 302, marginLeft: '5.4%', marginRight: '5.4%', }}>
                <Image source={require('../Images/user_icon.png')} style={{ position: 'absolute', width: '100%', height: '90%', borderRadius: 10, backgroundColor: MAGENTA_COLOR_CODE}} />
              </View>
            }
            keyExtractor={item => item.id}
          />
        </View>
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  button: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#DDDDDD',
    padding: 10,
    width: 300,
    marginTop: 16,
  },
});
```

Please help me out. I am unable to fix it as I am new to the React Native.

Here is the screenshot:

[image: unable to scroll down due to view height]

Comment: Could you update the screenshot?

Comment: DONE. I am unable to scroll down as the main view has taken the height of FlatList content size.

Comment: why do you want to set the view's position as Absolute?

Comment: @SDushan actually there will be three views, and I have to hide and show based on condition, that's why I kept it as absolute to set all three views together one upon another.

Comment: if you want to render view according to conditions check this - https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html.

Comment: Okay. I'll check. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this out

first render items from Flatlist and return view of Flatlist item

```
 render() {
return (
  <View style={{flex: 1}}>
    <FlatList
      extraData={this.state}
      data={sampleNameArray}
      keyExtractor={item => {
        return item;
      }}
      renderItem={this.renderItem}
    />
  </View>
);
```

this is your main render method and then render the items and adjust your list style in the next render and use style as described **style={styles.stylename}**

```
 renderItem = ({item}) => {
return (
  <View>
    <View style={styles.body}>
      <Text style={styles.text}> {item.data1}</Text>
      <Text style={styles.text}> {item.data2}</Text>
      <Text style={styles.text}> {item.data3}</Text>
    </View>
  </View>
);
```

and you can set how you want to render your item , like i do like this 
then you can set CSS property to each and every element.

Hope it will gonna work for you

Comment: Thanks, Anuj. I'll check this.

Comment: yeah Sure , and please mark my question with green tick if you find it helpful.